# Error for installing latest vue-cli npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! syscall mkdir npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, npm-install

I tried to install vue-cli on my vscode, I ran this command:
npm install -g @vue/cli

this is what my terminal shows:

~ % npm install -g @vue/cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/*****/.npm/_logs/2023-05-03T03_54_58_307Z-debug-0.log

what can I do in this case?

I tried to change the owner and its not working.

Answer (score 0):

EACCES errors can occur on recent versions of MacOS because security has been tightened.

Try following the steps here to re-install npm with a node version manager which should stop these errors from happening:
https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally